# How to install Java on Snappy?

Tags: java, ubuntu-core

So far doing something very basic like installing Java onto this new "better" version of ubuntu called snappy is about the most painfully frustrating thing to do.  I just want to install a java sdk.  Forums are so far zero help and since this "great" new "simple" version doesn't allow downloading things from the internet with a simple apt-get command (a whole 2 seconds to perform) i'm now stuck looking on forums for the equivalent new "quick and easier" method snappy has designed to do this for an extremely long time with no success.

Anybody know what the design for this new ubuntu version is for installing a basic package to the system?  I just need a java SDK to be installed and for the life of me cannot figure this out.

Comment: Do you insist on using snappy? The old way still works.

Comment: Due to the requirements of the project i'm working on, snappy (ubuntu core) is necessary.  Not sure what you mean by "the old way still works".  Nothing about snappy works with the old way, otherwise I'd have been done with a simple apt-get command.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu Core is aimed at *devices* not humans :)

The new packaging format in Ubuntu Core, called the "snap", is very strict and deterministic. All the files in a snap are not modifiable, by you or a hacker, and they can be updated automatically. This is *great* for millions of devices in the field, but it's not fun for a human.

I would suggest you start at https://snapcraft.io/ to find out more about making a snap of your software. You would make a snap using the familiar, friendly, "classic" Ubuntu desktop or server, and that snap can then be installed on either "classic" or "snappy" systems like Ubuntu Core. The idea is that developers use a friendly and easy place like "classic" Ubuntu for development, but they *ship* snaps to devices (or other systems). If docket and apt-get had a baby, it would look like a snap :)

Hope that helps. Check out https://rocket.ubuntu.com/channel/snapcraft which is a web forum we are trying out... that happens to be run from a snap :) or you can find us in #snapcraft on Freenode. To try out Rocket and get a feels for how your oapp can be distributed neatly as a snap, try `sudo snap install rocketchat-server` then point your browser at http://localhost:3000/

Comment: So in my case where I didn't necessarily want to generate a snap (looks like i'm going to be forced to) and just wanted to install java onto the OS, this is not possible with snappy?

Comment: So much text and so little use to answer actual question...